# Webform Download Results not working

Tags: webforms, files

I have been trying to get the download results of a webform and it has'nt worked

Here are the steps I have followed

[image: I click dowload here]

[image: I recieve this and click on the link]

[image: And here is the message I recieved]

I have checked the temp folder and .tmp files have been generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have selected third option of 'Download Range Options' and its working properly.

[image]